# Analytic functions exercises - Complex analysis by Ahlfors

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

I am new to Complex analysis, and I want to understand it so I've studied it by Ahlfors's text. I've just read a few sections and these are exercises/proofs that I want to understand (The chapter is Complex functions).

**The proof.**
The text proves the result that (the letter $z=x+iy$)

> $u(x,y), v(x,y)$ have continuous first-order derivatives satisfying the Cauchy-Riemann differential equations, iff $f(z)=u(z)+iv(z)$ is analytic with $f\in C^1$

I don't understand the proof. The proof says that under the assumption of $u,v$ that
$$u(x+h,y+k)-u(x,y)=\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}h+\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}k+\varepsilon_1$$
$$v(x+h,y+k)-v(x,y)=\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}h+\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}k+\varepsilon_2,$$
where $\varepsilon_1/(h+ik),\varepsilon_2/(h+ik)\longrightarrow 0$ as $h+ik\longrightarrow 0$. How is this possible? Does this (last assertion) need the "continuous" partial derivative. I am quite familiar with one variable if it's written as ($\varepsilon\rightarrow 0$ with $h$)
$$f(x+h)-f(x)=f'(x)h+\varepsilon h,$$
as it is the definition of derivative itself. The text then goes on by using the Cauchy-Riemann equations to obtain (this is okay if the above occur)
$$f(z+h+ik)-f(z)=\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}+i\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)(h+ik)+\varepsilon_1+i\varepsilon_2,$$
and this is almost the analyticity we desired. So the question remains why we have the above? Why it seems to be seperable into 2 equations like that?

**Now the exercises.**

> 1. Prove that the functions $u(z),u(\bar{z})$ are simultaneously harmonic.

*Attempt.* I am not familiar with more than 1 variable again. But I think this argument is okay but how it is done in systematic way? I think that we must show that if $u(x,y)$ is harmonic then
so is $u(x,-y)$ (and vice versa)?
First, I prove that $$\dfrac{\partial^2 u(x,-y)}{\partial x^2}=\dfrac{\partial^2 u(x,y)}{\partial x^2}\mid_{y=-y},$$
which means finding derivatives then replace $y$ with $-y$. This is not true for first-order partial derivative of $u(x,y)=x^3+y^3$.
By using the above and assuming $u$ is harmonic we obtain
$$\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}u(x,-y)+\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}u(x,-y)=\left\{\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}u(x,y)+\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}u(x,y)\right\}\mid_{y=-y}=0.$$
The proof of the above is from one variable as only $y$ changes, I let $g(x)=-x$ so $f(-x)=(f\circ g)(x)$ so
$$\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}(f\circ g)(x)=\dfrac{d}{dx}(f'(g(x))g'(x))=f'(g(x))g''(x)+g'(x)^2f''(g(x))=f''(-x)=\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x)\mid_{x=-x}.$$

> 2. Prove rigorously that the functions $f(z),\overline{f(\bar{z})}$ are simultaneously analytic.

*Attempt.* I think the rigorous he mentioned may need to modify the above proof of the theorem (and since I don't understand I don't know how to proof).

At first I thought it is possible to use 3. by setting $g(w)=\bar{w}$ but $g$ is not analytic unfortunately. Then, I write $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ and so $\overline{f(\bar{z})}=u(x,-y)+i(-v(x,-y))=:u_0(x,y)+iv_0(x,y)$ (not sure again if I'am right). Then, with the same as 1., I think it's possible to compute that $u_0,v_0$ satisfy the CR-equation (the change of variable does not affect the continuity of the derivative). Then, applying the theorem, we are done.

> 3. If $g(w),f(z)$ are analytic functions, show $g(f(z))$ is also analytic.

This is where I copied the argument in wiki for the chain-rule of real function of real variable. Thus,
$$\dfrac{(g\circ f)(z)-(g\circ f)(z_0)}{z-z_0}=\dfrac{(g\circ f)(z)-(g\circ f)(z_0)}{f(z)-f(z_0)}\cdot\dfrac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0},$$
and each term exists as $z\rightarrow z_0$ (the first holds since $f$ is continuous). Is this okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\L}{\mathscr{L}}\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$Precise theorem statement and proof clarification:

> Suppose $\Omega\subseteq\Bbb R^2$ is nonempty and open; suppose that $u,v:\Omega\to\Bbb R$ are *differentiable*.
>
> Then, identifying $\Omega$ as a subset of $\Bbb C$, $f:\Omega\to\Bbb C,\,z\mapsto u(\Re z,\Im z)+i\cdot v(\Re z,\Im z)$ is *differentiable* in $\Omega$ iff. $u,v$ satisfy the C-R equations: $$\partial_1 u=\partial_2 v,\,\partial_1 v=-\partial_2 u$$
>
> (By magic, differentiability of $f$ at every point suffices to show $f$ is analytic (infinitely differentiable and locally representable by a power series) and it follows that $u,v$ are actually smooth)

---

Tl;Dr - don't worry about the "continuously" differentiable hypothesis. But do bear in mind that "$u$ is differentiable" is **not** the same thing as "$u$ has all partial derivatives".

The assumption that $u$ is *differentiable* means that (the partials exist and): $$\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{|u(x+h,y+k)-u(x,y)-\partial_1u(x,y)\cdot h-\partial_2u(x,y)\cdot k|}{\|(h,k)\|}=0$$For all $(x,y)\in\Omega$. That means precisely that, with $\epsilon_1$ defined to be the function $(h,k)\mapsto u(x+h,y+k)-u(x,y)-\partial_1u(x,y)\cdot h-\partial_2 u(x,y)\cdot k$, defined as a real valued map on a suitable neighbourhood of zero, we have: $$u(x+h,y+k)-u(x,y)=\partial_1u(x,y)\cdot h+\partial_2u(x,y)\cdot k+\epsilon_1(h,k)$$And: $$\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{\epsilon_1(h,k)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=0$$So it is true that, considering $\epsilon_1$ as valued in $\Bbb C$, $\epsilon_1(h,k)/(h+ik)\to0$ as $h+ik\to0$. This part does **not** require $u$ to be *continuously* differentiable.

All of this is the same for $v$. *The property of the error $\epsilon$ having $\epsilon/\|(h,k)\|\to0$ is the main point of the derivative*, in higher dimensional settings. One generalisation - the [Frechet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative) is based pretty much completely on this point. You say "it's just the definition of derivative itself": I can say the same even in multivariable calculus.

Moving on. If the C-R equations are satisfied, then for a fixed $(x,y)\in\Omega$ it is correct (this *still* does not need the "continuity" hypothesis) just by definition of $f$ and some algebra that, with $z:=x+iy$ for fixed: $$f(z+s)-f(z)=(\partial_1u+i\partial_2v)\cdot s+\epsilon_1+i\epsilon_2$$For all fixed $z\in\Omega$ ($z=x+iy$ for some $x,y$) and displacements $s$ which are sufficiently close to zero ($s=h+ik$ for some $h,k$) where $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ are both $o(s)$ as $s\to0$ (this is a brief way of saying, $\lim_{s\to0}\epsilon(s)/s=0$).

This implies: $$\lim_{s\to0}\frac{f(z+s)-f(z)}{s}=\partial_1u+i\partial_2v$$So by very definition, $f$ is differentiable at every point. I still don't need $u,v$ to be continuously differentiable!

About the converse, if $f$ is *differentiable* at each $z$ then by taking displacements $s$ which are purely real we can infer $f'=\partial_1u+i\partial_2v$ at all points: specifically, let $s\to0$ along the real axis and let $x=\Re z,y=\Im z$. Then: $$\begin{align}f'(z)\longleftarrow&\frac{f(z+s)-f(z)}{s}\\&=\frac{u(x+s,y)-u(x,y)+i\cdot(v(x+s,y)-v(x,y))}{s}\\&\longrightarrow\partial_1u(x,y)+i\partial_1v(x,y)\end{align}$$Similarly if you take $s=it\to0$ along the imaginary axis then: $$\begin{align}f'(z)\longleftarrow&\frac{f(z+s)-f(z)}{s}\\&=\frac{u(x,y+it)-u(x,y)+i\cdot(v(x,y+it)-v(x,y))}{it}\\&\longrightarrow(-i)(\partial_2u(x,y)+i\partial_2v(x,y))\end{align}$$So it follows (since both quantities equal $f(z)$) that: $$\partial_1u+i\partial_1v=\partial_2v-i\partial_2u$$Taking equality of the real and imaginary parts we get the C-R equations right back.

**The continuity of the derivatives of $u,v$ or $f$ were still unnecessary hypotheses**. *However*, as mentioned at the top of the post, $u,v$ are *forced* to be continuously differentiable and indeed *smooth* (infinitely differentiable). So technically speaking your text is not making any superfluous hypotheses, but you never need to worry about it: to reiterate, if $u,v$ satisfy the C-R equations and are **differentiable** (this is *not* the same thing as having partial derivatives!) then they are necessarily also $C^1$ and even $C^\infty$, so you don't need to check that the derivative is continuous.

The proof of why all of that is forced is too long to fit here; the relevant theory will be covered by your text soon, I hope.

---

> "I think we must show that if $(x,y)\mapsto u(x,y)$ is harmonic then so is $(x,y)\mapsto u(x,-y)$?"

Maybe - to be honest, I find the phrasing ambiguous. However they are both harmonic, **always** (there is no "if this ... then that..."). By the "magic", it is necessarily true that $u$ and $v$ are $C^2$ so it's ok to talk about the second order partials, but it's worth noting that this is not trivial. For this exercise, feel free to assume it is true.

Hint: to show $\partial^2_{11}u=-\partial^2_{22}u$, think about $\partial^2_{11}u=\partial_1(\partial_1u)$ and about the C-R equations. Also think about "the equality of mixed partials".

Your idea for the second exercise is correct. You want to show $u_0:(x,y)\mapsto u(x,-y)$ and $v_0:(x,y)\mapsto-v(x,-y)$ satisfy the C-R equations iff. $u$ and $v$ do. Note that $u,v$ are differentiable iff. $u_0,v_0$ are differentiable is also true (try to justify this). So, $f$ is differentiable iff. $z\mapsto\overline{f}(\overline{z})$ is differentiable (so one is analytic iff. the other is analytic, by magic!).

For the third, it's almost ok. I think it's a good exercise to test the C-R equations hold for $g\circ f$ (directly) but what you did is almost fine - you just need to handle the possible problem that $f(z)=f(z_0)$ (in which case, your expression is undefined).

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I think I did write the statement not exactly true fron the text, so I just realize it from your answer. It is what I want about the $\varepsilon$'s things. For the first question, I am not sure if this means that $f(z)$ (that corresponds to $u(z)$) is analytic? Then, this means that if it is, $u$ always harmonic as you said? The problem does not state it so I am not sure if this holds without any condition.

Comment: @W.Wongcharoenbhorn I'm sorry I forgot to reply to this. The precise statement is what I place at the beginning of my answer: if $u,v$ are **differentiable** (*not* the same thing as having partial derivatives), in some open $\Omega\subseteq\Bbb R^2$, and satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations, then $f$, so defined, is always analytic. Proving that is beyond the scope of the proof in your post. In this proof / my answer, we only show $f$ is differentiable. Using more advanced techniques we can also show $f$ is analytic

Comment: @W.Wongcharoenbhorn And in the situation that I state precisely at the top of my post - and in my other comment - it follows $u$ is always harmonic, yes